# Getting 401 unauthorized error in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, retrofit

Error `401 unauthorized` means request is denied due to invalid credentials. I am making request to `https` URL using retrofit and getting `401 unauthorized` while doing `curl https://external:userName@api-staging.xyz.com/user/get` it works perfectly for me (getting expected output).

There is nothing wrong with the `Retrofit` implementation in my `application` because other calls is working fine. Is that something that I cannot pass such URL to `retrofit.setEndpoint`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that Retrofit does not support putting the username and password in the URL (due to security reasons).
This kind of authentication is called Basic Authentication, and you can pass these parameters in an HTTP header as well.

Here's an article about how that can be done in Retrofit: https://futurestud.io/blog/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit/